# Set default header in Nodejs request module

Tags: node.js, request

I need a default header to be attached for every API calls happening in my node js. For example TRACE-ID i'll pass it to backend and based on this id i can search my logs easily.

Comment: you are sending trace-id from client?

Answer (score 0):

You should use some middleware like [express-pass-id](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-pass-id) to create, assign and pass custom headers with your trace id.